# Reactjs Component Structure and creating new entries for Child Components

Tags: reactjs

I have a Categories component that gets it's data (an array of flat object literals) and then lists the data in a child Category component:

## Categories.jsx

```
var Categories = React.createClass({
    render: function () {

        // this.state.categories is already defined as is array of objects
        // example: [{categoryID: 1, categoryName: 'Test', ...},]
        this.state.categories.map(function (category) {
            categories.push(<Category category={category} key={category.categoryID} />);
        });

        return (
            <div className="categories">
                {categories}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

## Category.jsx

```
var Category = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="category" id={this.props.category.categoryID}>
                <div className="toggle">
                    <input type="checkbox" className="toggle-category" checked={this.props.category.isActive} />
                </div>
                <div className="name">
                    {this.props.category.categoryName}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I need to make it so that when the user Clicks on a category (or an `edit` button in the category that has yet to be put in) I need to load that data into a `form` that is populated with the `Category` props (as dictated to it by the `Categories` state);

However, every time I've tried (via state, props, etc.) the `defaultValue` is never initialized with the correct data as the `defaultValue` is usually empty because I'm getting the category data via Ajax.

## EditCategories.jsx

```
var EditCategory = React.createClass({
    render: function () {

        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.category.categoryID} />
            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

which is in turn mounted like this in `Categories.jsx`:

```
<EditCategory category={this.state.categoryBeingEdited} />;
```

I can successfully get the `categoryBeingEdited` to update via click events in `Categories.jsx` and dispatching a `CATEGORY_SELECTED` action, but I'm not sure how to allow editing of the state of `categoryBeingEdited` as the mount of `EditCategory` only ever happens once, so loading into text field with a previously set `defaultValue` is, again, impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my least favorite things about React. The solution we use is to not use `defaultValue` and set `value` to a state variable when the input changes. For example (note that this is untested):

```
var EditCategory = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {categoryID: this.props.category.categoryID};
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    this.setState({categoryID: nextProps.category.categoryID});
  },

  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({categoryID: event.target.value});
  },

  render: function () {

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.categoryID} />
        </div>
    );
  }

});
```